# How can you fill width of a RatingBar in Android without creating additional stars?

Tags: android

I have a RatingBar in my app, wrapped inside of a CardView for rounded corners. I need the rating stars to fill the width of the cardview evenly to create 5 stars, not more.

Currently I have

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/rating_container"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/description"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/spacing_normal_3x"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_normal_2x"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_normal_3x"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/app_rating_box_color"
                app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                app:cardElevation="0dp">

                <RatingBar
                    android:id="@+id/rating"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:numStars="5"
                    android:stepSize="1"
                    android:theme="@style/RatingBar" />


            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

As you can see, I have 5 stars, and this works great. But it looks like this

[image]

I want it to be like this

[image]

but without having more than 5 stars basically. Ideally, they would be spaced evenly apart to fill the width of the box. If it is a smaller screen, then they would have less space in between them. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

As the stars are not represented as views in the class RatingBar, but customly drawn, its hard to edit the display behaviour.

You could create a custom RatingBar like this (untested example code):

```
public class CustomRatingBar extends LinearLayout {
    private int stars;

    public CustomRatingBar(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            ImageView star = new ImageView(context);
            addView(star);

            LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) star.getLayoutParams();
            params.weight = 1;
            params.setMarginStart(10);
            params.setMarginEnd(10);

            star.setOnClickListener(v -> setStars(indexOfChild(v) + 1));
        }

        setStars(0);
    }

    public void setStars(int stars) {
        this.stars = stars;
        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
            ImageView star = (ImageView) getChildAt(i);
            star.setImageResource(stars > i ? R.drawable.star_shown : R.drawable.star_hidden);
        }
    }
    
    public int getStars() {
        return stars;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();

        getLayoutParams().width = 0;
    }
}
```